# Set a minimum file size for wget images scraped

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I am attempting to scrape images, however, I want to not download images below 5kb. Is there any way to set a minimum file size in my wget subprocess?

I looked around and can't seem to find how to anywhere.

```
results = subprocess.check_output(['wget', '-r', '-nd', '-P', '/datadrive/peeled-images', '-A', 'jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png', www.arandomurl.com], stderr=subprocess.STD
```

Looking to set a minimum file size of 5kb